# Disadvantages of save() version 2 in R?

Tags: r

An R object can be saved using `save()`

Objects saved that way require R >= 3.5.0 in order to `load()`

So, to make a data file more accessible (i.e. to some earlier R versions), we can use `save(... , version = 2)`

Are there any disadvantages of doing so?

For reference, from `?save`

> **version** - the workspace format version to use. NULL specifies the current default format (3). Version 1 was the default from R 0.99.0 to R 1.3.1 and version 2 from R 1.4.0 to 3.5.0. Version 3 is supported from R 3.5.0.

Comment: I don't have enough contextual knowledge to comment on this, but the NEWS for the new format says this: *"R has new serialization format (version 3) which supports custom serialization of ALTREP framework objects. These objects can still be serialized in format 2, but less efficiently. Serialization format 3 also records the current native encoding of unflagged strings and converts them when de-serialized in R running under different native encoding. Format 3 comes with new serialization magic numbers (RDA3, RDB3, RDX3)."*

Comment: @Gregor very interesting. Sounds like 'efficiency' is one disadvantage. The other one sounds potentially serious (presuming that it means that save version 2 will occasionally de-serialize strings correctly). I wonder how often 'unflagged strings' occur in the wild?